# Insert column at runtime into datagridview and SQL Server database simultaneously C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

My datagridview is connected to a SQL Server database. I know how to add column at runtime into the datagridview.

But my question is that inserting column at runtime in datagridview creates a column also in database? If yes: why?

If no, how to add column simultaneously in datagridveiw and database at runtime?

Comment: Did you try it? Of course adding a column to your gridview is NOT going to add a column to your database. If you want to add a new column to both you would first add it to your database and then include the new column in the resultset that you use to populate your datagridview.

Comment: @seanLange i have tried it. if i add in datagrid, it doesnot add in database. if i add in DB, it doesnot show up in datagrid. 
I have searched for the method that can add column simultaneously in both tables but in vain. :(

Comment: Of course it doesn't add to your database. That would be unbelievably awful. If you add the column in your database and THEN query the database, including the new column, it would appear in your grid.

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you think you need to add them simultaneously?

Comment: @stuartd i don't know the number of columns user gonna add. and i want to keep the data of the user in the database.

Comment: OK, let's just say for the sake of conversation. You present a datagridview to the user. They add a column and in a perfect world that column is created in the DB. Why would you need anything different as the datagridview has the new column and the DB has the new column? But I digress. Allowing the user to dynamically handle the structure of a database is not a good practice. Perhaps you could have a secondary table of usercolumns and populate any additional columns off of that.